# manipulating property file based on row numbers

Tags: java, properties

I'm setting properties like i show under. If i have the value of what i want to retrieve ("a", or "3", or both), is there any way to get the row number of what  I'm searching for?

example:"show me the row number where the second argument is "2"" would return 2 while "show me the row number where the first argument is "a"" would return 1

also is it possible to do a search based on the row number?
example: "give me the second argument of row 3", would return "3" while 
"give me the first argument of row 1" would return "a"

```
        try {

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("a", "1");
            properties.setProperty("b", "2");
            properties.setProperty("c", "3");

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            properties.store(fileOut, "prop name");
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve it.

```
  File progFil = new File("...");
  Properties pro = new Properties();
  try{

  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(propFile);
  pro.load(in);
  System.out.println("All values of the property file : ");
  Enumeration em = pro.keys();
  while(em.hasMoreElements()){
  String str = (String)em.nextElement();
  System.out.println(str + ": " + pro.get(str));
  }
  }
  catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

would return:

All values of the property file :

a:1

b:2

c:3

Answer (score 0):

The Properties are being stored as key/value pairs, so you can only retrieve  the data from properties based on the key. However, you could also use the list method which I don't believe would maintain any kind of order. Then, you could search thru that output.

The following code writes the properties into a file, PropertiesList.txt. You can search this file for whatever you need.

```
package listproperties;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ListProperties {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("a", "1");
            properties.setProperty("b", "2");
            properties.setProperty("c", "3");

        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("PropertiesList.txt")); 
            properties.list(pw);
            pw.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }            
    }    
}
```

Comment: how would I move all data into a list?